# A non-numeric value encountered in kallyas theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using kallyas theme, and in contact page I get error. The problem is that I never changed everything in this file.

```
A non-numeric value encountered in /wp-content/themes/kallyas/pagebuilder/elements/contact_form/contact_form.php on line 906
```

line 906:

```
$id = $id +  self::$form_id + '_';
```

Comment: Replace the `+` with `.`. I suppose.

Comment: This is original file. I changed but same.

Comment: remove `+ '_'` and check (don't remove semicolon after it)

Comment: I changed php version to 5.6 and it works

Comment: so now you have to remove the question because it's version issue

Comment: In PHP, we concatenate strings using the `.` operator, not `+`, which is (mostly) used for addition. PHP throws the error because we can't perform addition using the string `'_'`. Line 906 should be: `$id = $id . self::$form_id . '_';`